# NoReverseMatch for form using django-select2

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2, django-urls

I have two view section, one of them saves the fields into database and the other is to autocomplete a field. How can I use both of them in a html template?

First View:

```
def stock(request):
stocks_form=StocksForm(None)
if request.method == "POST":
    stocks_form =StocksForm(data=request.POST)
    if stocks_form.is_valid():
        instance=stocks_form.save()
        instance.user=request.user
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request,"Successful" ,extra_tags="savestock")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Error!")

else:
    stocks_form=StocksForm()
return render(request,'BallbearingSite/stock.html',{'stocks_form':stocks_form})
```

Second View:

```
class StocksAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Stocks.objects.none()
        qs = Stocks.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^stock/$',views.stock,name='stock'),
url(r'^stock_autocomplete/$',views.StocksAutocomplete.as_view(create_field='name'),name='stock_autocomplete'),
```

Project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
url(r'^ajax_select/', include(ajax_select_urls)),
url(r'^admin/BallbearingSite/controlsite/$',views.sendemailview),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^',include('BallbearingSite.urls', namespace='BallbearingSite')),
url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
url(r'^login/$',views.user_login,name='login'),
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
 ]
```

Template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
{% csrf_token %}

{{ stocks_form.as_p }}

<input id="savestocks" type="submit" name="" value="ثبت">
</form>
```

forms.py:

```
  class StocksForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta():
    model=Stocks
    fields=('name','number','suffix','brand','comment','price')
    widgets = {
        'name': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='stock_autocomplete')
     }
    def clean_name(self):
     return self.cleaned_data['comment'].upper()
```

It has this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /stock/

Reverse for 'stock_autocomplete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments'{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

It highlighted these parts in error :

```
    {{ stocks_form.as_p }}
```

and :

```
   return render(request,'BallbearingSite/stock.html',{'stocks_form':stocks_form})
```

Comment: How are imported your urls? Can you please show the urls.py of your project?

Comment: you mean these urls `? url(r'^stock/$',views.stock,name='stock'),
url(r'^stock_autocomplete/$',views.StocksAutocomplete.as_view(create_field='name'),name='stock_autocomplete')`

Comment: No, I mean the urls of your django project. This seems to be the urls of your stock app.

Comment: i added it to the codes above

Comment: Great! As mentioned by @Alasdair, it shows that you are using a namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be missing the namespace from the url. If the `stock_autocomplete` url is in the `BallbearingSite` namespace, you would do:

```
'name': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='BallbearingSite:stock_autocomplete')
```